# Different default values for Model siblings Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model

I am using an inherited modelling schema for my site, it has every media element under one common PolyModel base with every different element by themselves like so:

```
class STSeasonMedia(polymodel.PolyModel):
    season = db.ReferenceProperty(STSeason,collection_name='related_media')
    description = db.StringProperty()
    visible = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    priority = db.IntegerProperty(default=10)
```

So I want the "Inheriting" Models to have some other fields but also different default values, for example:

```
class STVideo(STSeasonMedia):
    video_id = db.StringProperty()
    provider = db.StringProperty()
        priority = db.IntegerProperty(default = 100)

class STThumb(STSeasonMedia):
    picture = db.ReferenceProperty(STPicture,collection_name='thumbs')
    url = db.StringProperty()
    size = db.StringProperty()

class STNote(STSeasonMedia):
    content = db.TextProperty()
    visible = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    priority = db.IntegerProperty(default = 1)
```

Is there a way to set this different default values, they may change afterwards but in the beginning must by those values. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried the code you've shown? If not, does raise some kind of Exception?

Comment: Yeah, it does! That's why I'm trying to look for a valid alternative.

Comment: Can you include the Exception traceback in the question? I'm not sure if it will help find an answer in this case, but it's usually a good idea, just as a general principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution may be to provide an `__init__` method to your derived models. It can provide a modified default value for certain properties if none was provided by the user.

For example, your STVideo class, which wants a different default `priority` should be able to use this:

```
def __init__(self, priority=100, **kwargs):
    super(STVideo, self).__init__(priority=priority, **kwargs)
```